# How can I limit the number of items scraped per domain in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on scraping items from across a number of websites(using scrapy for the same).
The items I am trying to scrape are not always well defined and might be within texts. So I am using string matches to recognize items. However, this also yields some unwanted information along with my required data and my scraper takes a long time scraping unwanted information.
To avoid this, I have put an upper limit on the number of items scraped. By using an "if" condition, I am raising a CloseSpider() exception on reaching the upper limit.
This approach worked fine until I had only one domain to scrape. How do I extend it for multiple domains.

```
class CustomSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "myspider"
start_urls = ['https://www.example1.com/']
allowed_domains = ['www.example1.com']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_info', follow = True)]

def parse_info(self, response):
    scrape_count = self.crawler.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count')
    if scrape_count == 20:
        raise CloseSpider("Limit Reached")
```

My question is, how to extend this code for the following scenario:

```
class CustomSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "myspider"
start_urls = ['https://www.example1.com/', 'https://www.example2.com/']
allowed_domains = ['www.example1.com', 'www.example2.com/']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_info', follow = True)]

def parse_info(self, response):
```

suggest change in logic here

```
    scrape_count = self.crawler.stats.get_value('item_scraped_count')
    if scrape_count == 20:
        raise CloseSpider("Limit Reached")
```

Comment: it depends on how you are relating an `item` to a `domain`, does it have a field that indicates to which domain it belongs? something like `item = {'domain': 'www.example2.com'}`?

Comment: Currently it does nothing like that. Assuming I do this part, how can I achieve the desired logic?

Answer (score 4):

See this toy example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import collections
try:
    from urllib.urlparse import urlsplit
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlsplit

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
                  'http://webscraper.io/test-sites']
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com', 'webscraper.io']

    scraped_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    limit = 10

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_page',
                  follow=True, process_request='process_request')]

    def parse_page(self, response):
        yield {
            'url': response.url
        }

    def process_request(self, request):
        url = urlsplit(request.url)[1]
        if self.scraped_count[url] < self.limit:
            self.scraped_count[url] += 1
            return request
        else:
            print('Limit reached for {}'.format(url))
```

It keeps track of the number of items scraped per domain in attribute `scraped_count`. Attribute `limit` holds the limit per domain. The logic is put inside the `process_request` method that's passed as an argument to [`Rule`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) and that gets called for every request extracted by that rule (see the documentation). When you are over the limit, request gets filtered, otherwise it's returned unchanged and gets processed.

If you need something more sophisticated or applicable to multiple spiders, I'd suggest you extend [`CloseSpider`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/closespider.py) extension class, implement the logic there and replace the default class in the `settings.py`.

Comment: Hi @Tomáš Linhart , thanks for the suggestion. This is close to what I want.
But I am not trying to filter the requests after reaching the limit. I want the spider to stop sending requests to that domain..and once the limits to all the domains have reached, the spider stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-itemcount)**

> An integer which specifies a number of items. If the spider scrapes
>   more than that amount and those items are passed by the item pipeline,
>   the spider will be closed with the reason closespider_itemcount.
>   Requests which are currently in the downloader queue (up to
>   CONCURRENT_REQUESTS requests) are still processed. If zero (or non
>   set), spiders won’t be closed by number of passed items.

Comment: Hi parik...I am able to set limit for the number of items scraped by the spider.
I want to set a limit on the number of items "per domain" in my start_urls.

Comment: if you want that  spider to stop sending requests to that domain, you can count the item of each domain and put them in one variable or dict, before sending a request, you can have a condition if the number of items are less than the number that you want

Comment: This is what @Tomáš Linhart's solution is about..I am looking for a more sophisticated way of making scrapy understand to not generate more requests rather than me stopping the requests

Answer (score 0):

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 100,  
    }
```